# Is there a free python debugger that has watchpoints?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, watchpoint

pdb and winpdb both seem to be missing this essential (to me) feature.  I saw something suggesting WingIDE has it but I'd prefer a solution that is free, and if I do have to pay, I'd prefer to pay for something that is better than Wing.

Comment: Why was this marked as off-topic? Please reopen.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look what pydev in eclipse offers...

Comment: Care to add some links to examples?

Comment: It looks like watchpoints are not yet implemented in pydev.
http://www.mail-archive.com/pydev-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02350.html

Comment: Actually, that link is to an old reference... Watch expressions should be working on PyDev now (just select the code you want, right click > watch -- or maybe use the console during a debug session for prints: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html )

Answer (score 4):

You should check out [Eric4](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/)

It's a very good Python IDE with a builtin debugger.
The debugger has views for global variables, local variables and watchpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PyScripter](http://mmm-experts.com/Products.aspx?ProductID=4). It has an integrated debugger, watch windows and much more.
It's open source and is developed [here](http://pyscripter.googlepages.com/).

HTH

Comment: PyScripter looks interesting but I'm on OS X and the P4D stuff appears to be only for Windows/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It's too bad that the standard pdb module that comes with python itself does not yet support watchpoints.

Described here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PdbImprovments

Answer (score 1):

This reimplementation of the built-in pdb.py has watchpoints.

http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2008/06/pdb-and-rlcompleterng.html

I tried it but, in cursory tries was not able to get it to work.

Comment: Agreed. The 'watch' command did nothing.